# JQuery - Cannot select elements based on their index

Tags: jquery

Lets assume I have the following html:

```
        <ul class="list">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
```

I cannot do something like this: (using .get() and refering by index value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').get(0).html('some_text')
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) returns the DOM element, not a jQuery selection.  The `html` method is a jQuery one, not a DOM one.  You need [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').eq(0).html('some_text')
});
```

Comment: I believe if he was set on using get, he could do something like `$('li').get(0).innerHTML="some_text";` as well.

Comment: @Vap0r In this case, yes. I get the impression the OP is referring to the general case, however.

Comment: However, I have noted this works. $($('li').get(0)).text('some_text'); anyone care to explain why?

Comment: @Awais The jQuery constructor (`$`) takes either a selector string (e.g. `li`) or a DOM element.  The DOM element returned from the `get` call is passed to the jQuery constructor, which creates a new jQuery selection containing that element.